# GCP K8s (kubectl) error message (Required "container.leases.get" permission)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, google-iam

I am getting an error message after running some kubectl commands (GCP command line - gcloud). I have a K8S cluster created in GKE.

Example:

> kubectl describe node

***gke_k8s_cluster_name
Error from server (Forbidden): leases.coordination.k8s.io "gke_k8s_cluster_name" is forbidden: User "MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT" cannot get resource "leases" in API group "coordination.k8s.io" in the namespace "kube-node-lease": Required "container.leases.get" permission.***

The point is that "container.leases.get" permission is not listed in IAM (as custom permissions or regular role).

How could I grant that permission to the service account in GCP ?

thanks,
Jose

Comment: Since leases are a recent feature, can you tell which GKE version are you using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking. It says 1.14.10-gke.27 (default) - Static version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to grant additional permissions to yourself on GCP IAM and GKE sides, for example:

```
PROJECT_ID=$(gcloud config get-value core/project)
USER_ID=$(gcloud config get-value core/account)
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_ID} --member=user:${USER_ID} --role=roles/container.admin
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole cluster-admin --user ${USER_ID}
```

See also [GCP IAM & GKE RBAC integration](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam).

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex! The original issue (error message) is fixed. I can execute the kubectl CLI commands smooth!